# How to implement users top on Redis with zsets

Tags: redis, sortedset

For example I have 10 000 users who playing the game. Each user can win or lose points during the game a few (may be 100 or 1000) times per hour.
I need to show top 10 users by points win for last 1 hour. Top list should be updated each minute.

So I need to store and update 60 (mins in one hour) zsets per each win or lose. Old zsets will be automatically deleted by expire.

Other way is to store user points by minute in hset (only one hincrby per each win or lose) and recalculate values for zset using this data each minute. In this case I should take 10 000 hkeys each minute, delete old data (older than one hour) in each key, sum other data and create new zset for displaying.

Both cases is not liked by me because count of users can increase by several times or other tops can be added in the future.

Can this implemented another way in Redis?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you trying to display the top ten users sorted by net points gained during the last hour, or cumulative total score (if that's applicable)?

Comment: Yes, i try to show users sorted by net points during the last hour.

Answer (score 3):

The catch is how you define "last hour". It is much simpler to do it with "clock hour" as opposed to "last 60 minutes". I'll explain how to do the clock hour given it's simplicity

You can use HINCRBY with negative numbers. So, if I understand you correctly, you should be able to have a single hash for each hour, with an expiration to auto-remove old hours.

When a user finished their game you do:

HINCR "leaderboard:hournumber" userid

That will give you the points gained or lost in that hour.  Now to get the top 10, for example, you'd need to go the HGETALL route to pull it all back and do sorting on the client side.

To leverage the caching aspect you could then store the resulting "top X" user/points values in an key (such as storing it as JSON) which expires every N minutes. With that the process which display the ranking would pull that key and display if found, otherwise generate/store/display the result. Alternatively or in addition to the above you can have a scheduled job which calculates and stores the results for display every minute.

Because it is possible (even if rare) for users to have the same net point change I wouldn't go with a sorted set where the point total is the score.

To do it with a rolling window you'd could do something along the lines of a per-minute hash as above instead of per-hour (maybe leaderboard:minutenumber) and on the calculation side figure out what minute number you are on right now and do the HGETALL on the previous 60 minute hashes in a pipeline. Of course, set the per-minute hashes to expire after 60 to keep usage lower.

Doing it this way means you calculate keys as opposed to querying for them.

I suspect you could also do the summary aspect with a Lua script but as your client-side grows and calls to it increase it would be more horizontally scalable to do those calculations on the client.

Comment: What about ZINCRBY instead of HINCRBY, so you don't have to do the sort client side? I would take your key-per-hour-number approach btw, which is a good idea for multiple reasons including easy of access, expire, ...

Comment: @antirez I initially started there (I'm a sucker for sorted sets I suppose), but backed away from it because I felt the complexity of translating that to the "rolling 60m window" route would push a lot of computation to Redis that I'm not sure should be there and generally try to avoid in a horizontally scalable client model. That and to handle ties you either accept the reverse lexi order or roll your own. Doing it all client-side lets you choose which. Otherwise sorted sets would work fine.

Comment: Oh yes, if rolling window is needed it is definitely a concern, if a discrete solution is acceptable the zset approach is likely the best. One thing that may be acceptable from the POV of many products is to always show the last hour window while populating this hour window. However in the case of a game, perhaps a more "real time" feeling is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Ok here I'm trying to provide  a different solution compared to the one provided by Bill, with disadvantages and advantages at the same time, in order to provide an alternative. With this solution you get:

1. Top N without client side sorting.
2. Rolling window.

However it is a bit more expensive from the POV of memory and computationally.

This is how it works:

1. You have the `topn` key which is populated with ZINCRBY with the real time data. If we imagine to do this forever, what happens is that you don't have any rolling window, but the "all time top N", so we need a fix for this.
2. You also take an additional sorted set, one for every minute of the last ~2 hours (as long as it has more than 1 hours should be ok). So actually every time an user score is updated, you do ZINCRBY to `topn` and also to `topn_<minute>`.
3. You have an additional process that does the following: for each `topn_<minute>` entry which is no longer inside the current hours, it subtracts its scores from the `topn`. This should be possible with a single ZUNIONSTORE call, using as AGGREGATE "SUM". It is important to delete it (in a transaction) at the same time, so we are sure we remove it a single time.

Because we only have SUM, there is a trick here. Actually in step "2" you have to populate the `topn_<minute>` with *inverted* values. Positve for negative scores, negative for positive scores.

Ok it's night and I'm not sure I got all the details right, but the general idea should work, to have one main key, and other keys in order to subtract what is no longer within the current hour.